# IndexOf returns -1 in foreach object in list

Tags: c#, list, indexing

When I run the code, it returns -1, although the object (in my understanding) has to be there, since it's being produced by the foreach statement.
Does anyone have an idea?

```cs
public partial class Class1
{
    private List<Master_Menu_Item> Config
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Master_Menu_Item>>(Json_string.Config); } //if you need an example json, i can provide it
    }

    private void Reload_Master_stack()
    {
        if (Config != null)
        {
            foreach (Master_Menu_Item master_Menu_Item in Config)
            {
                int index = Config.IndexOf(master_Menu_Item);
                Debug.WriteLine(index);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Master_Menu_Item
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Icon_path { get; set; }
       public List<Bottom_Menu_Item> Bottom_Menu_Items { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: My guess is that `Master_Menu_Item` overrides `Equals`, but does it badly. We can't really tell from just this code. Please provide a [mcve] - it should be complete, but not contain anything irrelevant.

Comment: Show us how `Config` is declared.

Comment: Please read [mcve] so that you understand what is meant by [mcve]. The edit is appreciated, but fails to provide the [mcve] that is needed in order to understand your question.

Answer (score -2):

You can use below code:

```
 if (Config != null)
            {
                foreach (Master_Menu_Item master_Menu_Item in Config)
                {
                    int index = Config.FindIndex(a => a.Id == Master_Menu_Item.Id );
                }
            }
```

Comment: for this to work, i have to add the "id" definition to my Master_Menu_Item class. is this the only way to go or am I missing something?